# assign IP from text file

Tags: powershell

I have a scenario where I have below details in log.ini file.

```
Hostname    : DLC1MQF
IP Address   : 10.210.208.102
Temporary IP : 10.212.215.91
Subnet Mask  : 255.255.248.0
Gateway      : 10.212.208.1
```

What I am really looking here is I want check Default gateway is pinging or not. if not pinging I need to capture the IP,Subnet and Gateway from log.ini and assign that to my NIC.

Currently I am able to write a script like below and the problem is I am getting an error message that else is not a recognised command here.

```
$imagelog = Get-Content C:\Windows\ImageLog.ini
foreach ($line in $imagelog) {
if ($line -like "*Gateway*") {
$line | out-file -FilePath "C:\Windows\Gateway.txt"
}
}

$gatewayIP = get-content c:\windows\Gateway.txt
$GIP = $gatewayIp -replace '.*:.'.Trim()


if ( Test-Connection -ComputerName $Gip -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) {
Write-Host $GIP `t $GIP `t Ping Success -ForegroundColor Green

}

else{

$details = get-content c:\windows\imagelog.ini

foreach ($line in $details) {
if ($line -like "*IP Address*") {
$line | out-file -FilePath "C:\Windows\IP Address.txt"
}
#}


$IP = get-content c:\windows\IP Address.txt
$systemip = $Ip -replace '.*:.'.Trim()

foreach ($line in $details) {
if ($line -like "*Subnet Mask*") {
$line | out-file -FilePath "C:\Windows\subnet.txt"
}
}

$subnet = get-content c:\windows\subnet.txt
$subnetip = $subnet -replace '.*:.'.Trim()


netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static $systemip $subnetip $GIP

foreach ($line in $details) {

if (Hostname.StartsWith("LCG")) {

Set-DNSClientServerAddress –Local Area Connection –ServerAddresses (“10.0.6.65”,”10.0.25.65”,"10.0.0.1")

}

elseif (Hostname.StartsWith("ENG")) {


Set-DNSClientServerAddress –Local Area Connection –ServerAddresses (“10.80.38.33”,”10.0.25.65”,"10.0.0.1")

}
}
}
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the test-connection in a try/catch block

```
Try{
    test-connection $IP -ErrorAction Stop | out-null
    write-output "working"
    ...do working stuff...
}Catch{
    ...do failed stuff...
    write-output "failed"
}
```